# Why is "Colls" an empty Array?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I try to judge a player's approach to a monster using "OverlapSphere." 
But somehow it doesn't work the way I want it to.

Is there anything wrong with the code below?

```
    bool IsPlayerNear()
    {
        Collider[] colls = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, 3f);        
        foreach(Collider hit in colls)
        {
            if(hit.gameObject.tag == "Player")
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The player character has a capsule collider and "Player" tag.

But the "colls" array contains nothing.

Comment: Does the player have a rigidbody?

Answer (score 0):

A frequent cause of this sort of problem is that the capsule collider is attached to a child or parent of the tagged gameobject, so maybe check that, your code looks OK to me.